# Is using dynamic types to get values from anonymous objects bad practice?

Tags: c#, dynamic, anonymous-types

Note: My question is not about ASP.Net.

I have a GridView bound with an anonymous collection using LINQ.

I want in an event handler in the grid get a value from the bound object which is not able to cast to any static type because its type is anonymous.

To solve this problem I used dynamic type to get the value

```
protected void MyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        dynamic dataItem = e.Row.DataItem; // getting the bound object

        bool isCurrentEntity = dataItem.IsCurrentEntity;
        if (isCurrentEntity)
            e.Row.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontWeight, "Bold");
    }
}
```

My question is that is using the dynamic type here is a bad practice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would call that a bad practice, yes. If you want to use the anonymous type in multiple places in the code then it is important enough to make it a nominal type. Remember, dynamic *starts the compiler again*, which is a serious performance cost, and it *trades convenience for the developer in exchange for hiding bugs to be discovered by the user*, which is a serious customer relations cost.

Dynamic was designed to make code that was *already* going to be slow and brittle more pleasant to read. If you were already going to be using reflection, or already going to be talking to a legacy COM automation object, then you were *already* going to be in a world of slow, dangerous code. It might as well be easy-to-read slow dangerous code. If you can avoid being in that world, do it; use a nominal type.

Alternatively, if you want to use an anonymous type *and* have it be statically typed, use the 'cast by example' trick:

```
object anon;
void M1()
{
    anon = new { X = 123, Y = 456 };
}
void M2()
{ 
    // we want to get anon.X, but it is anonymous. How do we
    // trick the compiler into it?

    var cast = CastByExample(new { X = 0, Y = 0 }, anon);
    int x = cast.X;  // gets anon.X!
}

static T CastByExample<T>(T example, object ob) where T : class
{
    return (T)ob;
}
```

Sneaky, eh?  The cast by example trick uses generic type inference to say "I think this object over here has the same anonymous type structure as this one here".

Note that cast by example *only works in the same assembly*.  You cannot cast by example an anonymous type created in one assembly into an anonymous type created in another.

Comment: Is the compiler always started for dynamic?  What happens when the object that the dynamic variable references implements IDynamicMetaObjectProvider?  For example, using ExpandoObject with dynamic.

Comment: @Joshua: Right, if the DLR determines that some other code is in charge of resolving the dynamic call then the C# runtime engine is not started up.

Comment: @Eric: That is sneaky! Although I'm not sure I would usually want to use that adjective to describe my code.  :)  Would you characterize the trick as an implementation detail (albeit one that probably wouldn't change)?

Comment: @Tuzo, no it is not an "implementation detail". Everything in there works according to the documented rules. In particular, the spec says that two usages of "the same" anonymous type in the same assembly are actually the same type, which is what makes this legal.

Comment: @Eric @Tuzo maybe just for the sake of completeness: Argument order matters. new { X = 0, Y = 0 } and new { Y = 0, X = 0 } are two different types.

Comment: @Michael: another reason to, as Eric said, create a nominal type and avoid the runtime `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Eric, the spec actually says "in the same program" should it actually say 'in the same module' or some other description for a unit of compiler output, IIRC the current c# compiler only ever emits single module assemblies so it's fine to state 'same assembly' in this regard if someone's being normal. I'm slightly concerned that someone might think that they can mess about with assembly linker to 'unify' such things across separate compiler runs though.

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: I take your point, but I am not worried at all about that. Anyone sophisticated enough to use a tool to combine multiple netmodules into a single assembly I assume also has a sophisticated and realistic understanding of how types work in the CLR.