# Re-hydrating an object passed via AsyncCompletedEventArgs

Tags: c#

I'm constructing an anonymous object:

```
    var userToken = new {myMsg = Msg, myTimer = timer};
```

and passing it to an event handler:

```
    smtp.SendCompleted += SendCompletedCallback;

    private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var msg =  e.UserState;
    }
```

Inspecting `msg` shows that it contains the values I've passed but I'm not clear on the syntax that allows me to access those values in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To improve Jordao's answer:

```
private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic msg = e.UserState;
    MyMessageType myMsg = msg.myMsg;
    MyTimerType myTimer = msg.myTimer;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since that is an anonymous object, you can access the properties using `dynamic` or the [cast-by-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448410/is-using-dynamic-types-to-get-values-from-anonymous-objects-bad-practice/5450369#5450369) technique.

Ideally, though, you'd create a strongly typed object for that data.